# new django app's from 1.1 causing 500 error

Tags: python, django, centos

i'm running on wsgi on centos 5...

i've recently updated locally from 1.0 to 1.1

I updated the server using svn update

now when I apply a new app developed locally to the server it returns with a 500 error.

all i'm doing is python manage.py startapp appname

adding the app into installed_apps in the settings file and uploading

this then causes a 500 error... anything that would be causing this?

Comment: You'll need to check your log files. Try flipping on DEBUG by settings DEBUG = True in settings.py.

Comment: the only error referring to my project is

[Wed Aug 05 22:15:01 2009] [error]  File "/home/***/urls.py", line 8, in ?

which the line 8 is

admin.autodiscover()

DEBUG is True but it just comes back with a 500 error

Comment: What are the contents of the 500 page itself?

Comment: Internal server error....?

thats all 500 pages give out.

Comment: When DEBUG = True Django often provides more info on the 500 page. What's in your web server error log?

Comment: You should use DEBUG = True and set your IP in INTERNAL_IPS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Didn't we solve this for you in IRC the other day? If not, there was someone with the same OS and vague problem description.

Turned out to be a third-party app causing the problem, not the newly added one (which a review of the trackback proved if read carefully)

Comment: yes chris, that it was me... I posted this before I cam into IRC... great job on your part thou!

Comment: is this an answer?  accepted one?

Answer (score 1):

Check also the list at http://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/BackwardsIncompatibleChanges.